# C++ using struct member during initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

Is it correct to use the member of a struct that we are initializing? My compiler does not complain with the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  int a, b;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo {34, foo.a + 2}; // I'm using `foo.a` during the `foo` initialization
    std::cout << foo.a << "   " << foo.b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

// Prints "34   36"
```

But it seems weird since `foo` is not declared yet when I use it inside the braces.

Comment: On a side note, it is bad design IMO. If `b` depends on `a`, `Foo`'s constructor should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine and valid as long as you keep `a` declared before `b` as you're doing right now.